# Should questions on S#arp Architecture be moved to Stack Overflow from Google Groups?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, forums

As those that use it know, the forum on [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture) has all discussions as well as technical questions.

I'd suggest moving the technical questions here and leaving the forum for more general discussions on the code, the meta questions if you like.

Does anyone agree or indeed have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

There is a discussion on the podcast and a [blog article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/) by Jeff on how the R community went about this. Do it likewise - and yes, leave out the discussion part.

Comment: @Ralph, spot on, exactly along the lines I was thinking.  +1 and think this would be a great way to go and to bring more folk into s#arp architecture too.

Answer (score 1):

Slice off the discussions and bring on the technical questions and answers!